# Don't find ExpressionTable, AttributeTable module in perl

Tags: perl

I found a [perl project](http://llama.mshri.on.ca/cgi/download/download.pl?software=ClusterJudge). I want to run that project. But it needs some modules like:

1. ExpressionTable
2. AttributeTable

I used cpan for install modules but it does not find it and also I don't find it in search.cpan.org.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for it?

Comment: what is the project?

Comment: the project's link is here(http://llama.mshri.on.ca/cgi/download/download.pl?software=ClusterJudge)

Answer (score 1):

The modules aren't from CPAN. I expect they are supposed to be included in the downloadable tarball for the project, but that doesn't seem to be the case - the directory labelled "lib" only seems to contain .pl files, no .pm files.

To be honest, I'd be really wary of using that code. It seems to have been written by someone with very little idea of how to write sharable and maintainable Perl code. For example, it contains `use lib` lines that point to Windows directories belonging to a specific user (which, obviously, won't exist on anyone else's systems).

There's a support email address on the download page for the project. They will be far more likely than we are to be able to help you with this.